# Is there a way to search by a specific language using Google App Engine Search API?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When you create a `Document` object, you can specify the language of the document: 
See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/documentclass

Now, let's say I want to search for documents with language = 'en'.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: As far as I can tell, from a quick perusal of the source, the language is only used to change how the input fields are tokenized -- you can't search for it.  If you want to search for it, you'd need to add that as an extra field and add it to the query string as @Julldar demonstrates.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

As the doc you provided points out, you can do :

> index.search("product = piano AND price < 5000")

so I guess in your case :

> index.search("language = en")

Or do you mean "I want to do a full text search on english documents only"?

Let's assume that's what you meant.... you can actually do it if you follow what this doc says :

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/query_strings#Python_Mixing_global_and_field_searches

> index.query("keyboard great language=en")

will (according to doc, I haven't tested to be honest) look for "keyboard great" in all documents with "language=en"

[EDIT] Since, as mgilson pointed out, the "language" field is non queriable for documents, you cannot do this out of the box, I think the only solution is to add a "language" field to the search fields of your document and search using the method explained in the rest of this answer :)

Comment: I don't think this is what OP meant.

Comment: I don't see what he wants.  I provided a way to grab all documents with language=en, and a way to using the search API in documents with language=en.... what do you think he meant then?

Comment: Search API documents have a language attribute which can be passed to the constructor that _isn't_ a search field.  OP wants to know if they can filter the results by this.

Comment: Oh the language ISN'T a search field? I was convinced it was.  Yeah my bad then.  But... for simplicity, couldn't he just add a "language" queriable field and use that?

Comment: aaaand I just saw your comment on the question :P so yeah I think this is the only viable solution

Comment: It's the only solution that I can come up with although I'm not an expert here -- I've only used it for a little while.  FWIW, I _did_ take a very quick search through the source and didn't find anything helpful there ...